# If cell is true, then add on the same row a certain value

Tags: vba

I linked several checkboxes to their own cells. If I check the checkbox "A17", the checkboxes B19:B28 will get checked - And if I uncheck A17, the contrary will happen. But, I would also like to add on the same rows of these checked cells ("B19:B28") two differents values on column F, G.

This is my code:

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
   
If Range("A17") = True Then
   For Each cell In Range("B19:B28")
       cell.Value = True
   Next cell
   Else
       For Each cell In Range("B19:B28")
       cell.Value = False
   Next cell
End If
   
End Sub
```

And I don't know how to follow up...!

Comment: Like `cells(cell.row,"F").value=1` or you could use `Offset`?

Comment: How could I use Offset in my example? Thank you!

Comment: E.g. `cell.offset(,4).value=1`, it's equivalent to my previous example. Not sure I know what you're asking exactly.

Comment: My for loop gives a checkmark on each row B19:B28, I want at the same time, on the same row but different column to be able to add 2 other values

Comment: Are those pointers not sufficient?

Comment: not really - im terrible with vba :(

Comment: Nvm! got it to work thanks to you!